# Why check if isset($_POST['Submit']) before accessing other $_POST elements?

Tags: php, arrays, post, submission, superglobals

What is this code doing? If Isset, and what are the variables doing, whats the $_POST doing? Can someone explain please?

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $forename = $_POST['forename']; 
    $surname=$_POST ['surname'];
    $dateofbirth=$_POST ['dateofbirth'];
    $gender=$_POST ['gender'];
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $passcode1=$_POST ['passcode1'];
    $passcode2=$_POST ['passcode2'];
```

Comment: Are you a programmer?

Comment: You might want to read some basic PHP tutorials (or better: books).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a form is being submitted,  then it assigns variables.

Comment: Thank you, nice and simple to understand.

Answer (score 3):

$_POST contains the data from the form the user submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

is checking to see if a form was submitted. There is likely a hidden element with this name, or the submit button was created to include this value.

The remainder of the lines copy*1 the information out of the POST super global into easier to use variables.

(*1 not actually copied, PHP is copy on write)

Comment: Note that $_POST['Submit'] is not sent with every form, it is most likely a hidden form field named "Submit" sent along when the form was submitted.

Comment: Thank you, i have understood what the code is doing. I am trying to understand a large amount of code which i have been left in charge of by a friend who could not finish the project. So am going through it bit by bit to understand before i can add my own adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

It will check If the form is submitted set the value of html elements in to the PHP variables that's it.

These variable can be used for further processing and later to store in database.

Answer (score 1):

So here is an attempt to answer your amorphous question.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

This line is checking to see if an entry called 'Submit' is present in the $_POST array.
[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a function that checks the existence of variables in PHP.

`$_POST` is a [global variable in PHP that captures the key-value pairs sent in an HTTP POST request](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php).  `$_POST` will contain the result of an HTML form submission in 99% of the use cases.

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
```

is setting the title variable in the PHP script to the title field in the post array.  title was probably a text field submitted by a form.

Looking at the use of $_POST in your example code, the request to the php script probably comes from a form that looks like:

```
<form method="post" name="someForm" action="thatScript.php">
<input type="text" name="title"/>
<input type="text" name="forename"/>
<input type="text" name="surname"/>
... other inputs that correspond to $_POST entries...
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/> <!-- the submit field that is checked in the isset -->
</form>
```

Notice: `<form method="post"`
This tells the browse to submit the key-value pairs for the form in a post request.  If that line read `<form metho="get"` then the browse would submit the key-value pairs as a get request and the php script would check and use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Thank you, i have looked through the code, and indeed there is a similar form to one you just typed. I am trying to understand an awful lot of code which a friend left me in charge of. Many thanks. However, the for looks like this:   <label>D.O.B  : </label>
        
        <td>
            <input name="dateofbirth" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['dateofbirth'])){  echo $dob; } ?>" />
        </td>
    what is this snippet of code doing?.. I understand it is creating a form name called 'dateofbirth', but what is the rest doing?

Comment: It is setting the default value for the dateofbirth field of it exists in $_POST['dateofbirth'].

Answer (score 1):

It checks if the form has been submitted and if its true then values from post array (that are sent by the sending page) are assigned to variables.

for example value for this `$_POST['title']` is assigned to *variable* `$title`.